# Foreground service issue - did not then call Service.startForeground()

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

Found an interesting observation with foreground service, if we stop the service immediately right just after start foreground service we get this error as **Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()**. Doesn't matter whether we start notification from onCreate or onStartCommand of service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class)
startForegroundService(intent);
stopService(intent);
```

But if I add a delay then it's working as expected, any thought on this ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class)
startForegroundService(intent);
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> stopService(intent), 0);
```

**In order to get rid of this error this is how I fixed**

> I didn't found any proper documentation on developer website but this is what
> I did in order to solve **Context.startForegroundService() did not
> then call Service.startForeground()** issue.
>
> If we want to stop foreground service do not call outside the service
> class using **stopService(intent)** instead create an intent action,
> start the foreground service then stop the service using stopSelf from
> service onStartCommand.
>
> ```
> Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
> serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
> ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a service is not synchronous and the service is not up and running when the start call returns. Think of it as posting a message to your main thread looper queue that get processed later.

Now your Handler approach is also doing the same kind of thing to postpone the execution - post a runnable to the main thread looper queue. It gets processed after the previous messages in the queue have been processed, so there's some `Service` startup lifecycle code that has been executed before the `stopService()` is invoked.

Comment: I am interested to get some documentation link where this thought is described. I found documentation about showing notification should be done within 5 seconds but couldn't get anything related to this. Actually if service is destroyed even before showing the service foreground notification then android system shouldn't throw this error at all.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma This is something related to above answer https://www.droidcon.com/2021/12/15/the-misbehaving-foreground-service-in-android/